# Jackson 2.* and json to ArrayList<>

Tags: java, json, jackson

I'm trying to deserialize a Json array to an ArrayList of objects. I have found some documentation on what i'm trying to do, but I'm getting an error on compile.

Here is how I'm trying to approach it with Jackson 2.2.2:

```
ArrayList<Friends> list =  objectMapper.readValue(result, new TypeReference<ArrayList<Friends>>() {});
```

The error I get is:

```
The method readValue(String, Class<T>) in the type ObjectMapper is not applicable for the arguments (String, new TypeReference<ArrayList<Friends>>(){})
```

I'm guessing some of the references I have been reading is based on an older version of Jackson. How can this be accomplished in Jackson 2.2 +

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try the following:

```
JavaType type = objectMapper.getTypeFactory().constructCollectionType(ArrayList.class, Friends.class);
ArrayList<Friends> friendsList = objectMapper.readValue(result, type);
```

Note that I pulled this from the following answer: [Jackson and generic type reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6846244/jackson-and-generic-type-reference)

As of Jackson 1.3 (a while back) they recommend you use `TypeFactory`.

**EDIT**

On further inspection, what you have above is working for me... I'm able to pass in a `TypeReference` sub class to `readValue` and everything works correctly.  Are you sure you have the right type of `TypeReference` imported?  Usually those types of errors are from accidentally importing the wrong type (some other library might have a `TypeReference` class).

Comment: Awesome. Exactly what was needed I just couldn't get the construction collection type right. Thanks Polaris!