# Jackson and generic type

Tags: java, android

I use Jackson to deserialize a generic type like this:

```
ListResponse<Product> = objectMapper.readValue(json, new TypeReference<ListResponse<Product>>() {});  
ListResponse<User> = objectMapper.readValue(json, new TypeReference<ListResponse<User>>() {});
```

and so on for every generic type the `ListResponse` will include.
This works OK, but I would like to create a method that will take as argument a generic type, and return a `ListResponse` of that generic type.

Something like this:

```
public static <T> T fromJsonWithListResponse(String json) {    
    return objectMapper.readValue(json, new TypeReference<ListResponse<T>>(){});
}
```

or this:

```
public static <T> T fromJsonWithListResponse(final Class<T> clazz, String json) {    
    return objectMapper.readValue(json, new TypeReference<clazz>(){}); // compile error
}
```

but it converts the result to a `LinkedHashMap`.

`ListResponse` is a wrapper class around `List`:

```
public class ListResponse<T> extends Response {
    private List<T> items;
    // other fields
    // getters and setters
}
```

Comment: Look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6846244/jackson-and-generic-type-reference?rq=1
That should work for your case as well.