# Class of generic class

Tags: java

I might blind some people here but I will fire anyway.

I know I can do:

```
Class<Response> c = Response.class;
```

To get the class of the object. Assuming that the Response object is `Response<T>` I want to do something like the following

```
Class<Class<User>> c =  Response<User>.class;
```

---

My full problem:

```
public class RequestHelper<T> extends AsyncTask<String, Response, T> {

    @Override
    protected T doInBackground(String... strings) {
       ...
       Response <T> r = objectMapper.readValue( result, Response.class );
       return r .getResponse();
    }
}

//and

public class Response <R> {
    private R response;
    public R getResponse() {
        return response;
    }
}
```

But above the parameter has not been specified in the assignment. In theory the correct way would require:

```
public class RequestHelper<T> extends AsyncTask<String, Response, T> {

    @Override
    protected T doInBackground(String... strings) {
       ...
       Response <T> r = objectMapper.readValue( result, Response <T>.class );
       return r.getResponse();
    }
}
```

But that generates a "Cannot select from parameterized type" lint error.

Alternatively I could pass the class in the constructor:

```
public class RequestHelper<T> extends AsyncTask<String, Response, T> {

    ....
    public RequestHelper(Class<Class<T>> tClass){
         this.tClass = tclass;
    }

    @Override
    protected T doInBackground(String... strings) {
       ...
       Response <T> r = objectMapper.readValue( result, tclass );
       return r.getResponse();
    }
}

// where the init of the class would have been:

 new RequestHelper<User>( Response<User>.class );
```

Comment: [Type erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) - There is no way to get information at run time about a generic type parameter, because it doesn't exist after compilation. Passing in a class explicitly is a common workaround.

Comment: Jackson provides types tokens for this.

Comment: I think you can't capture generic parameters within a class, but you can capture generic parameters within a subclass.  I think that might be what @SotiriosDelimanolis is referring to.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As the comments suggest, there is no such thing as

```
Class<GenericType<GenericArgument>>
```

Or rather, it doesn't do what you might think it does. Each type declaration (class, interface, enum, primitive) gets a single `Class` instance, whether it is generic or not.

As such, even if you have a reference of type `Class<GenericType<ArgumentOne>>` and another of type `Class<GenericType<ArgumentTwo>>`, the instance they are referencing will be exactly the same. What's more, there will be absolutely no way to query the type argument type.

You seem to be using Jackson's `ObjectMapper`. It provides a kind of *hack* for getting generic type information in the form of type tokens. You can use a `TypeReference` or `JavaType` instance to represent generic types. Examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6846244/jackson-and-generic-type-reference) and elsewhere around the Internet.

Comment: Thanks Sotiri. Particularly for the above I used `new TypeReference<Response<T>>() {}` as class parameter which sets and provides the type.

Comment: @Diolor Careful with `T` as the type argument, you're not providing any concrete type. Jackson will still use its defaults. This _hack_ only works with concrete types, not type variables.

Comment: Well...yes. The only way for the above `T` to work is to pass a constant type in the variable e.g. `@JsonDeserialize(as=User.class) private T response;` which is the same as `new TypeReference<Response<User>>() {}`. Dead end.

Comment: Sir, can you throw some light on the same issue I am facing: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45215475/android-generic-recyclerview-adapter-with-data-binding