# With Jackson - Using Method with Generic in Signature returns LinkedHashMap instead of Class

Tags: java, generics, groovy, jackson

I'm still struggling with some of the basic uses of Generics, this time with Jackson.  Neither of these work right.  The first returns a list of LinkedHashMaps instead of a list of type T.  The second can't see the variable "type" on the last line.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong :

```
public <T> List<T> readObjects(File file)
{
    File file = new File(subscriptionDir, fileName)
    return mapper.readValue(file, new TypeReference<List<T>>() {})
}


public <T> List<T> readObjects(String fileName, Class<T> type)
{
    File file = new File(subscriptionDir, fileName)
    return mapper.readValue(file, new TypeReference<List<type>>(){}) 
}
```

Thanks in advanced for any assistance.

Comment: The duplicate discusses Gson's `TypeToken` which is equivalent to Jackson's `TypeReference`. You cant do this using `TypeReference` nor the generic type parameter. You need concrete types. You can use the `ObjectMapper` to construct a `Type` that represents a `List<T>` if you have the `Class` object for `T`.

Comment: The solution proposed by varren looks like what I'm trying to do.  However, I'm actually using groovy, and it's detecting the curly braces as a closure:   {childrenClazz}  . Any ideas?

Comment: That's just an array initializer. Use whatever the groovy syntax for creating arrays is.

Comment: mapper.readValue(file,type) says it doesn't have a signature that takes a file , ParameterizedTypeImpl

Comment: Used Answer from staxman , was the best.  Construct a JavaType first, then pass that to the readValue method.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6846244/jackson-and-generic-type-reference