# How to test SpringMvc controller that returns pageable result with MockMvc?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, mockmvc

Using spring-boot 2.2.4.

I have a SpringMvc Controller that returns pageable objects:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/call-data")
public class CallDataController {
  @GetMapping
  public Page<CallDataDto> findAll(Pageable page) {
...
```

Trying to test it with MockMvc:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
MvcResult mvcResult = mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/call-data")).andReturn();
Page<CallDataDto> myDtos = mapper.readValue(mvcResult.getResponse().getContentAsString(), TypeUtils.pageTypeRef());
```

...

```
public class TypeUtils {
  public static <T> TypeReference<RestResponsePage<T>> pageTypeRef() {
      return new TypeReference<>() {
};
}
```

But instead of page with dto objects I get a page with LinkedHashMaps.

So how to get the page with dto objects?

Answer (score 0):

Similar question: [ObjectMapper using TypeReference not working when passed type in generic method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48804508/objectmapper-using-typereference-not-working-when-passed-type-in-generic-method?noredirect=1&lq=1)

You can solve the problem by replacing the type parameter(`T`) with `CallDataDto`.

```
public class TypeUtils {
  public static TypeReference<RestResponsePage<CallDataDto>> pageTypeRef() {
      return new TypeReference<>() {
};
}
```

Type parameters(e.g. `<T>`) don't exist at runtime so you have to replace them with some concrete values so that `Jackson` can obtain full generics type information.