# Jackson Unmarshall custom object instead of LinkedHashMap

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a Java object **Results**:

```
public class MetaData {
    private List<AttributeValue<String,Object>> properties
    private String name
    ...

    ... getters/setters ...
}
```

The **AttributeValue** class is a generic key-value class. It's possible different AttributeValue's are nested. The (value) *Object* will then be another AttributeValue and so forth.

Due to legacy reasons the structure of this object cannot be altered.

I have my JSON, which I try to map to this object.
All goes well for the regular properties. Also the first level of the list is filled with AttributeValues.

The problem is the *Object*. Jackson doesn't know how to interpret this nested behavior and just makes it a LinkedHashMap.

I'm looking for a way to implement custom behavior to tell Jackson this has to be a AttributeValue-object instead of the LinkedHashMap.

This is how I'm currently converting the JSON:

```
ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
MetaData metaData = om.readValue(jsonString, new TypeReference<MetaData>(){});
```

And this is example JSON. (this is obtained by serializing an existing MetaData object to JSON, I have complete control over this syntax).

```
{
    "properties":[
        {
            "attribute":"creators",
            "value":[
                {
                    "attribute":"creator",
                    "value":"user1"
                },{
                    "attribute":"creator",
                    "value":"user2"
                }
            ]
        },{
            "attribute":"type",
            "value": "question"
        }
    ],
    "name":"example"
}
```

(btw: I've tried the same using GSON, but then the object is a StringMap and the problem is the same. Solutions using GSON are also welcome).

**edit** In [Using Jackson ObjectMapper with Generics to POJO instead of LinkedHashMap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8903863/using-jackson-objectmapper-with-generics-to-pojo-instead-of-linkedhashmap) there is a comment from StaxMan:
"*LinkedHashMap is only returned when type information is missing (or if Object.class is defined as type).*"

The latter seems to be the issue here. Is there a way I can override this?

Comment: Did you check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22358872/how-to-convert-linkedhashmap-to-custom-java-object

Comment: Thanks. Yes I Did, but it's not a solution to my Issue. The MetaData object is created correctly, and there is a list of AttributeValues (on the first level).    The issue is on the second level, where the _Object_ should be replaced by another (nested) AttributeValue.

Comment: In http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8903863/using-jackson-objectmapper-with-generics-to-pojo-instead-of-linkedhashmap
StaxMan says: "_LinkedHashMap is only returned when type information is missing_ **(or if Object.class is defined as type)**" This seems like the cause, but I want to override this...

Comment: Can you give an example of the JSON to parse? It looks like the `AttributeValue` has a nested JSON object (i.e. `{}`) and because Jackson doesn't have any type info on the nested object, the generic deserializer kicks in. It's possible to solve this via a custom serializer but it's a little bit more work, so having an example JSON here would help.

Comment: thanks @dhke, I've added an example Json above. From what I've read I think that is indeed the way to go, but I don't really have a clue where to start.

Answer (score 2):

If you have control over the serialization, try calling `enableDefaultTyping()` on your mapper.

Consider this example:

```
Pair<Integer, Pair<Integer, Integer>> pair = new Pair<>(1, new Pair<>(1, 1));
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
String str = mapper.writeValueAsString(pair);
Pair result = mapper.readValue(str, Pair.class);
```

Without `enableDefaultTyping()`, I would have `str = {"k":1,"v":{"k":1,"v":1}}` which would deserialize to a `Pair` with `LinkedHashMap`.

But if I `enableDefaultTyping()` on `mapper`, then `str = {"k":1,"v":["Pair",{"k":1,"v":1}]}` which then perfectly deserializes to `Pair<Integer, Pair<...>>`.

Comment: Thanks @hotkey, I will try that. But if I understand this correctly, this will mean I have to write my Java-class into my JSON, which will couple them tighly together?

Comment: @user3319803, yes, including type info into JSON binds it to certain classes. But the binding is customizable: you can alter Jackson typing, for example, using `@JsonTypeInfo` on your class and changing mapper's typing. It can sometimes help you in dynamic/generic types deserialization even if you don't have control over the serialization, e.g. when you work with some API.

Comment: @user3319803, by the way, you can look through [this article](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonPolymorphicDeserialization) as an introduction, though it's about polymorphic desearilzation.

Comment: Thanks for the link @hotkey. Seems like a good introduction, and a potential solution to my problem.

Comment: I'd like for my JSON to be like this: `str = {"k":1,"v":{"k":1,"v":1}}` My JS frontend should not know about the classes of the backend. The @JsonTypeInfo seems to allow a lot of customization, but still keeps this coupling (if I understand correctly).

Comment: @user3319803, there's possible workaround in the referenced article:
"Sub-class list, using `class MyPojoList extends ArrayList<MyPojo> { }`  -- type information will be retained due to inheritance ("super-type token")".
So you can try to sublcass your `AttributeValue` and/or `List` containing it.