# Jackson 1.9.2 deserialization of List<RequestBeanType> returns List<LinkedHashmap>

Tags: java, jackson, deserialization

I am using Jackson 1.9.2 and I am trying to deserialize an object that I serialized using the same Jackson libraries. The object has list of type say List and deserializing this serialized string back to object results in List

I tried following the steps listed in related post - [Jackson is not deserialising a generic list that it has serialised](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6062011/jackson-is-not-deserialising-a-generic-list-that-it-has-serialised/13337453#13337453) but did not work for me.

I tried using both Typefactory and TypeReference in these ways:

1)

```
TypeFactory tf = TypeFactory.defaultInstance();

JavaType tr = tf.constructType(new TypeReference <RequestBeanType> () { });

mapper.readValue(json, tr);
```

2)

```
mapper.readValue(json, new TypeReference <RequestBeanType> () {});
```

3)

```
TypeFactory tf = TypeFactory.defaultInstance();
tf.type(RequestBeanType.class, Comparable.class));
```

In all three cases, I don't get back the list that I serialized using JSON. The deserialization always defaults list to

```
List<LinkedHashMap<RequestBeanType> when it should actually be List<RequestBeanType>
```

Any way around this?