# Generic method and JSON

Tags: java, json, generics, mapping

I wrote generic method which returns list of some objects, for example Orders. My question is why in second, non-generic method it returns correct list of Orders and the first method (generic) returns list of linkedHashMaps instead of Orders?

Generic:

```
 private <T> List<T> mapObjectsToList(String objectsListInJson) throws IOException {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    TypeReference<List<T>> mapType = new TypeReference<List<T>>() {
    };
    return objectMapper.readValue(objectsListInJson, mapType);
}
```

Non-generic:

```
private List<Order> mapObjectsToList(String objectsListInJson) throws IOException {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    TypeReference<List<Order>> mapType = new TypeReference<List<Order>>() {
    };
    return objectMapper.readValue(objectsListInJson, mapType);
}
```

Generic method returns that:
[LinkedHashMap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I6HpK.png)

Comment: You should take a look at some of these Q&As: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6062011/2891664 https://stackoverflow.com/q/6846244/2891664. This probably has to do with the use of the type variable in `TypeReference<List<T>>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the generic type variable `T` is not bound to any concrete type, so the compiler sees it as `Object`. So:

```
TypeReference<List<T>> mapType = new TypeReference<List<T>>() {};
```

is actually:

```
TypeReference<List<Object>> mapType = new TypeReference<List<Object>>() {};
```

And when the `ObjectMapper` can't gather info about the concrete type of the object to deserialize, it defaults to `LinkedHashMap`.

If you want to be able to deserialize to a generic type at runtime, you should pass the `TypeReference` type token as an argument to your `mapObjectsToList` method:

```
// Make this a singleton, i.e. don't create a new instance on every call!
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

private <T> List<T> mapObjectsToList(
        String objectsListInJson, 
        TypeReference<List<T>> mapType) throws IOException {

    return objectMapper.readValue(objectsListInJson, mapType);
}
```

And then use the above method as follows:

```
List<Order> orders = mapObjectsToList(
    stringWithTheJSON, 
    new TypeReference<List<Order>> {});
```

On a side note, I've moved the `ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper()` statement outside the method. There should be only one `ObjectMapper` instance in the whole application, unless you require different configuration for serializing/deserializing.

Comment: Ok, so what is the difference when I do method private List<Object> mapObjectsToList(String objectsListInJson) and private <T> List<T> mapObjectsToList(String objectsListInJson) ?

Comment: Thanks for answer! So what are generics for, if we can everywhere do it by using Object instead?

Comment: It's new TypeReference<Order>(), not <T> in that example :). But T is converted to Object anyway, so is there any difference in this case?

Comment: Ok, so TypeReference<List<T>> as argument is converted to Typereference<List<Order>> but method returned type (private <T> List<T> mapObjectsToList) is converted to Object or Order as well?

Comment: Ok, I understand now. Thank you very much. :)

Answer (score 0):

Because in the non generic method you have explicitly said that you are adding `Order`.

And in the generic one you are sending back `objects`, which are essentialy of type `Order`.

In any case both of it will return `List`.

Comment: Thank you for answer. So for every type of object which i want method to return list of objects, not linkedHashMaps, I have to write another method or is there any option to do this with generics?

Comment: @Ukis You can cast the objects to `Order`.

Comment: @Ukis If that helps can you please accept the answer?

Comment: I tried to do this: return (List<Order>) mapObjectsToList(ordersListInJson), but there's an error about Inconvertible types.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you can't pass a type parameter by simply declaring it.

Type parameters are erased so within your generic function `<T>` just not exist so even the type reference can't convey such info.

You should build the type reference with the actual reference of the class and pass a type reference to the method like this:

```
List<Composite> out = mapObjectsToList(in, new TypeReference<List<Composite>>() {});
```

or ...

Knowing in advance that you are deserializing exactly List of T you can play with `TypeFactory`

```
private static <T> List<T> mapObjectsToList(Reader objectsListInJson, Class<T> clazz) throws IOException {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    CollectionLikeType typeref = TypeFactory.defaultInstance().constructCollectionType(ArrayList.class, clazz);
    return objectMapper.readValue(objectsListInJson, typeref);
}
```

And call it like this:

```
List<Composite> out = mapObjectsToList(in, Composite.class);
```