# Error deserializing generic objects via jackson

Tags: java, generics, serialization, jackson, deserialization

I have the following 3 classes :

```
public class BaseClass<T>{
   private List<T> someList;
   ... constructor.....
}

public class Class1 extends BaseClass<BasePerson>{ .. constructor.. } 

public class Class2 extends BaseClass<Person> { ... constructor... }
```

When deserializing one of thew classes (Class1 or Class2) I get the following error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to com.somepackage.BasePerson
```

I saw some answers regarding this error, all advising using `TypeReference` or `TypeFactory`
here:
[answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6062011/jackson-is-not-deserialising-a-generic-list-that-it-has-serialised)
and here :
[another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11664894/jackson-deserialize-using-generic-class)

My problem is that i'm using jackson older version (1.9.2) and can't move to 2.0. Both `TypeReference` and `TypeFactory` were added in 2.0.0 API.

Anyone can advise what to do?

Comment: Such a version 1.19 doesn't seem to exist. Did you mean 1.9.1 ?

Comment: Yes - sorry - 1.9.2

Answer (score 0):

These classes are defined in Jackson 1.9. Pertinent docs [TypeFactory](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-core/javadoc/1.9/org/codehaus/jackson/map/type/TypeFactory.html) and [TypeReference](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-core/javadoc/1.9/org/codehaus/jackson/type/TypeReference.html)

You have here the case of a non generic class `Class1` extending a generic with a type `BaseClass<BasePerson>`. This is how I believe you would handle this with a `TypeFactory`

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
TypeFactory typeFactory = mapper.getTypeFactory();
JavaType baseType = typeFactory.constructParametricType(BaseClass.class, BasePerson.class);
JavaType type = typeFactory.constructSpecializedType(baseType, Class1.class);
```

and deserialize like this:

```
Class1 class1 = mapper.readValue(json, type);
```