# ClassCastException when deserializing with ObjectMapper onto parametrized class, even using TypeReference and TypeFactory

Tags: java, generics, jackson, deserialization, type-erasure

I'm getting the following exception when trying to deserialize with ObjectMapper onto a parameterized class (works fine for non-parametrized classes):

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to class com.xyz.A (java.util.LinkedHashMap is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; com.xyz.A is in unnamed module of loader 'app')
```

Here's the original code:

```
Foo<A> request = OBJECT_MAPPER.readValue(payload, Foo.class);
```

I tried:

```
Foo<A> request = OBJECT_MAPPER.readValue(payload, new TypeReference<Foo<A>>() {});
```

As well as:

```
JavaType myType = OBJECT_MAPPER.getTypeFactory()
    .constructParametricType(Foo.class, A.class);
Foo<A> request = OBJECT_MAPPER.readValue(payload, myType);
```

But I still get the same exception.

Could there be something special about my scenario that's not covered in these questions?

- [Jackson is not deserialising a generic list that it has serialised](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6062011/jackson-is-not-deserialising-a-generic-list-that-it-has-serialised)
- [Jackson and generic type reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6846244/jackson-and-generic-type-reference)
- [Jackson - Deserialize using generic class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11664894/jackson-deserialize-using-generic-class)

One thing I can think of is that my `Foo` is actually an `@AutoMatter`-annotated interface that generates the class:

```
@AutoMatter
public interface Foo<T> {
  Optional<T> parent;
  Optional<List<T>> children;
}
```

Normally we have no issues mapping onto AutoMatter-generated classes though. It's just adding the parametrization `<T>` that seems to be causing issues.

Does anyone have an idea?

---

**Edit to answer @MichalZiober's questions:**

In my test code I'm actually just serializing what I know is a valid object, *i.e.* then deserializing that to get back the object I started with:

```
Foo<A> myExampleObject;
ByteString.encodeUtf8(OBJECT_MAPPER.writeValueAsString(myExampleObject));
```

---

**Edit 2**

Okay, so it looks like we are already importing that module:

```
  @VisibleForTesting
  public static final ObjectMapper OBJECT_MAPPER = new ObjectMapper()
      .registerModule(new JodaModule())
      .registerModule(new GuavaModule())
      .registerModule(new AutoMatterModule())
      .registerModule(new Jdk8Module())
      .registerModule(new ProtobufModule())
      .setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
      .configure(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS, false)
      .configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_IGNORED_PROPERTIES, false)
      .configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false)
      .configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);
```

Comment: From which library `@AutoMatter` annotations comes from? Could you also post example `JSON` payload. Just to recreate given scenario. Do you use any custom configuration for `ObjectMapper`?

Comment: This one: https://github.com/danielnorberg/auto-matter

Answer (score 2):

When you use `Optional` in `POJO` structure you need to enable `Jdk8Module` from [`jackson-modules-java8`](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-java8). Below example shows that with this module registered we can serialise and deserialise data:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jdk8.Jdk8Module;
import io.norberg.automatter.AutoMatter;
import io.norberg.automatter.jackson.AutoMatterModule;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

public class JsonApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
        mapper.registerModule(new AutoMatterModule());
        mapper.registerModule(new Jdk8Module());

        String json = "{\"parent\":\"Aaaa\", \"children\":[\"a\"]}";
        System.out.println(mapper.readValue(json, Foo.class));


        Foo<StringWrapper> foo = new FooBuilder<StringWrapper>()
                .parent(new StringWrapperBuilder().value("PARENT").build())
                .children(Arrays.asList(new StringWrapperBuilder().value("CHILD1").build()))
                .build();
        json = mapper.writeValueAsString(foo);
        System.out.println(json);
        System.out.println(mapper.readValue(json, Foo.class));
    }
}
@AutoMatter
interface Foo<T> {
    Optional<T> parent();
    Optional<List<T>> children();
}

@AutoMatter
interface StringWrapper {
    String value();
}
```

Above code prints:

```
Foo{parent=Optional[Aaaa], children=Optional[[a]]}
{
  "parent" : {
    "value" : "PARENT"
  },
  "children" : [ {
    "value" : "CHILD1"
  } ]
}
Foo{parent=Optional[{value=PARENT}], children=Optional[[{value=CHILD1}]]}
```

Comment: ...wow. Thanks so much! Might take me a bit to get this to compile. I'll definitely follow up!

Comment: @AndrewCheong, hope that will help you. I know this is kind of opinion but some devs consider `Optional` fields in `POJO` like an [anti pattern](https://dzone.com/articles/optional-anti-patterns).

Comment: Oh, that's a great article. Yea, so it turns out we were already registering the Jdk8Module. (See edit #2.) But I'm gonna try removing all the Optionals and seeing what happens.

Comment: @AndrewCheong, I noticed your changes. Thats strange. You need to have a really complex `JSON` that probably `Jackson` can not resolve to a correct class. My answer does not provide anything new for you. Removing `Optional`s probably will not solve an error.

Comment: Well you've still shed light that the internal structure of the deserializing class actually matters. I had no idea about that. After removing Optionals, I'm gonna start simplifying my models to see at what point it starts working again, if any.

Comment: @AndrewCheong, just a guess but do you use maybe `Java 9+`? I am asking because I was trying to create very complex structures and it was working on `Java 8`. Maybe there is a strange class loader problem when we are working with [Java 9 modularity](https://www.baeldung.com/java-9-modularity). It is definitely worth to check in case you are using `Java 9+`.

Comment: @AndrewCheong, also I forget to ask which version of `Jackson` do you use? In case this is not the newest one try to upgrade it because I checked it for the newest `2.9.8`.

Comment: I'm actually on Java 11. And I was on Jackson 2.9.7. Not sure it's worth me reverting my code to see if 2.9.8 works, but it seems the culprit would more likely be Java 11.

Answer (score 0):

For now I just had to abandon parameterizing. I only had so many classes,

```
Foo<A>
Foo<B>
Foo<C>
```

It was easier to just create each one explicitly:

```
@AutoMatter
public interface FooA {
  A parent;
  List<A> children;
}

@AutoMatter
public interface FooB {
  B parent;
  List<B> children;
}

@AutoMatter
public interface FooC {
  C parent;
  List<C> children;
}
```

(I've also realized the `Optional`s were unnecessary.)

Not really an answer, so not accepting it.